Can I add a non integer multiple of a row to another row in gauss-elimination
Let's say I have the matrix.
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 2 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 3
\end{bmatrix}
Can I perform the operation $r_2-\frac{1}{2}*r_1$ on this matrix? I know this question is very simple but I don't recall if you can us non integer multiples of a row in gauss-elimination row-addition/subtraction.
Or should I just perform $r_1 * \frac{1}{2}$ and then $r_2 - r_1$?
Or are these equivalent?

You can perform either; both are correct.

@JulioPuerta Thank you.

I'm admittedly a slight bit unfamiliar with the notation you've chosen. The expression $r_2-\frac{1}{2}*r_1$ reads to me as though $r_2$ is the only row being transformed, whereas the latter scales $r_1$ by half and $r_2$ is transformed in the same way as before. Is this helpful at all?

@JAG131 The notation is just what my prof is using in his notes to show which  row operations are performed, so I'm using the same. In this example $r_2 - \frac{1}{2} * r_1$ and $r_1 * \frac{1}{2}, r_2 - r_1$ are two different ways to achieve the same goal. That is getting the second row to be $(0,0,1)$

@willaayy I see. So if we're not focused on the rest of the matrix, then there is no difference with regard toward achieving the stated goal.
